# iOS FBSDK making GraphRequests that are dependent on another GraphRequest - better way?

Tags: ios, facebook, swift

Is there a more efficient / cleaner way (than what I have below) to make graph requests that are dependent on the result of another graph request?

For the sake of this question, lets say I want to get the gender of the friends of the main app user. So first I make the graph request for the main user's friends, but then I need to nest graph requests for the various friends within the completion handler:

```
FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me/friends", parameters: nil).startWithCompletionHandler({ (connection: FBSDKGraphRequestConnection!, result: AnyObject!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
            let arrayOfFriends = result.valueForKey("data") as NSArray
            for friend in arrayOfFriends {
                let friendID = friend.valueForKey("id") as String
                FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: friendID, parameters: nil).startWithCompletionHandler({ (connection2: FBSDKGraphRequestConnection!, result2: AnyObject!, error2: NSError!) -> Void in
                        println(result2.valueForKey("gender"))
                })
            }
    })
```

So this turns out to work fine, but I was wondering if there is a better way to do this? I am worried about performance / readability of code if the nesting of requests is more than 2 levels.

Comment: You can define the handlers as separate functions to make this look more readable if that's your concern.